# What is galvano mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

What is galvano mirror? For what purposes is it used? Is it same with galvanometer? In the internet, galvano mirror is defined as "Scanning laser systems, whether for marking, engraving, or for drilling micro via holes, all rely on galvo mirrors to precisely position the laser beam". However I dont really understand its applications

Comment: The galvanometer principle is driving a mirror. Google gives you the answer in seconds see e.g Wikipedia German language (English site doesn't show the old days galvanometers)

Answer (score 1):

In a [mirror galvanometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_galvanometer) an electric current moves a mirror and a light beam is reflected by the mirror onto a scale. The greater the current the greater the deflection of the light beam.

In a galvanometer scanner the same technology of moving a mirror with an electric current is used to reflect and direct a laser beam. Because the mirror can be positioned very accurately, moved quickly, and has low inertia, this allows the laser beam to be scanned quickly and precisely across a target surface.

Applications include precision welding, precision laser cutting and high speed laser scanning. For more details take a look at the web site of a manufacturer of these products, such as [this one](https://www.cambridgetechnology.com/laser-beam-applications).